# Dictionary of Dataframes select name of the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am using Python.

I have a dictionary of Dataframes. Each dataframe has a name in the dictionary and I can reference it correctly no problem.

I am trying to take that name and add it as a column across every row. I am having a rough time doing this.

Comment: can you share an example of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply assign the name string to a new column for each DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

frames = {
  'foo': pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}),
  'bar': pd.DataFrame({'a': [9, 8], 'b': [7, 6]})
}

for name, df in frames.items():
  df['name'] = name
  print(df, '\n')
```

Gives:

```
   a  b name
0  1  3  foo
1  2  4  foo

   a  b name
0  9  7  bar
1  8  6  bar
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/ImpracticalJumpyBracket)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your dictionary and do below:

```
for key in d.keys():  # d is the dictionary of dataframes
    d[key]['new_col'] = key  # df_name is the name string you want to add in dataframe.
```

Comment: the name I want to add is the key, so just replace df_name with key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
frames = {k: v.assign(name=k) for k, v in frames.items()}
```